# «Несмотря ни на что» в конкретном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, запятые, выбор-варианта

> В подъезде, тихом, просторном и светлом,**(1)** несмотря ни на что,**(2)** висел унылый общественный дух, который не могли развеять ни сухоцветы в большой вазе раструбом, ни темно-зеленый ковер, ни блекло-желтая краска стен, — все это, очевидно, было выбрано по принципу безобидности.
> [Р. Гэлбрейт. Зов кукушки](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=25524&p=107)

Я несколько раз перечитывала это предложение, но так и не смогла определиться:
**чем** является ***несмотря ни на что*** в этом предложении — наречным или вводным выражением.
Правильна ли пунктуация? (По смыслу — нужны **(1)** и **(2)** запятые или только одна из них?)

Answer (score 4):

Ответ исправлен:

**В подъезде, тихом, просторном и светлом, несмотря ни на что висел унылый общественный дух...**

1) **Несмотря ни на что** ― обстоятельственный оборот, **не является вводным словом**. Может обособляться или не обособляться, как и любое обстоятельство, но чаще обособляется.

https://phraseologiya.academic.ru/710/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE

2) Если провести **интонационный анализ предложения**, то вопрос об обособлении оборота представляется мне таким.

Оборот будет обособляться (**как попутное замечание**) в следующем предложении:

В тихом, просторном и светлом подъезде,  **несмотря ни на что**, висел унылый общественный дух...

**Обособление связано с тем,** что прочитать первую часть предложения как одну фразу сложно.

А вот в приведенном предложении  обособлению оборота (с тем же значением) мешает обособленный ряд определений, поэтому оборот не обособляется, пауза отсутствует, сочетание ***несмотря ни на что висел унылый общественный дух*** читается как одна фраза.

Поэтому:

В подъезде, тихом, просторном и светлом, **несмотря ни на что висел унылый общественный дух.**...

И придется честно сказать, что прав оказался М.Г. Из всего сказанного можно сделать вывод о том, насколько значительное влияние на обособление (и на тесную связь со сказуемым) оказывает **структура предложения.**

Answer (score 3):

С одной стороны, Грамота пишет: "Обстоятельственный оборот "несмотря ни на что" в большинстве случаев выделяется запятыми"

С другой стороны, во многих конкретных случаях советует запятую не ставить:

> Вопрос № 279788
>   Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Несмотря ни на что хотелось верить в мечту"?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Запятая не требуется.
>
> Вопрос № 269882
>   Здравствуйте. Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Можно ли оставаться человеком несмотря ни на что?"
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Запятая не нужна.
>
> Вопрос № 226538
>   Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая: они добивались должного успеха (,) несмотря ни на что.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Запятую лучше не ставить.
>
> Вопрос № 204885
>   Шоу должно продолжаться несмотря ни на что. Нужна ли запятая? Спасибо.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Запятая не требуется.

Я бы одну из двух запятых не ставил, чтобы показать, к чему этот оборот относится в данном предложении. А при наличии двух запятых возникают споры. Так Jasmin пишет: "В приведенном примере оборот никак не связан со сказуемым висел, он относится к обособленному ряду определений, поэтому и сам обособляется". А по-моему, именно унылый общественный дух висел несмотря ни на что.

**В подъезде, тихом, просторном и светлом, несмотря ни на что висел унылый общественный дух, который не могли развеять ни сухоцветы в большой вазе раструбом, ни темно-зеленый ковер, ни блекло-желтая краска стен, — все это, очевидно, было выбрано по принципу безобидности.**

Comment: Унылый общественный дух висел несмотря ни на что? Вы это хотите сказать?

Comment: @Jasmin Именно так

Answer (score 0):

Обстоятельственный оборот "несмотря ни на что" в большинстве случаев выделяется запятыми. За исключением случая, когда он тесно связан со сказуемым.

НЕСМОТРЯ НИ НА ЧТО, в роли обстоятельственного оборота

**Обстоятельственный оборот «несмотря ни на что» чаще выделяется знаками препинания (запятыми).**

*Весеннее ли расположение подействовало на него, или толкал его кто сзади, только он протеснялся решительно вперед* ***несмотря ни на что.***  *Н. Гоголь, Мертвые души.*

> *Матушка, которая до самой смерти своей страстно любила его,* **несмотря ни на что,** *не могла выносить такой жизни. Ф. Достоевский, Неточка Незванова.*
>
> *Высокая, стройная, длинноногая, с мягкими белокурыми волосами и прозрачно-голубыми глазами, она мне нравилась,* *несмотря ни на что. К. Шахназаров, Курьер.*

Грамота.ру.

По поводу вводного. Найти информацию, что обстоятельственный оборот является вводным, найти не удалось. Кроме приведенного в одном из ваших ответов источника. Но вряд ли он заслуживает доверия.